# mysql trigger to change user status after a certain amount of points has been reached

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table users
in it there are columns
userPoints and userStatus

each user begins as a newbie.
if the userPoints reach 100
user status should change to something else

there is another table userStatuses
statusId statusName minPoints maxPoints

can I create a trigger that will fire off when userPoints reach 100 their userStatus changes, according to the userStatuses table?

**table statuses**

```
id  statusName  minimumPoints   maximumPoints

1   lvl1            0               100
2   lvl2            101             1000
3   lvl3            1001            5000
4   lvl4            5001            20000
5   lvl5            20000           100000
```

Comment: You should provide more information about table structure and used querys.

Comment: Yes, you can create a trigger, although assigning a level in application code based on level seems quite reasonable, if you keep the number of statuses reasonably small. It's usually easier & more clear for other developers if these kind of things happen in the application themselves rather then in triggers, and with about the same performance (and I imagine status changes are quite rare compared to other database operations).

Comment: yeah I was wondering which one was the better approach...

Comment: @Wrikken's suggestion is possibly better. Right now, you're keeping duplicate data in your database. (The # of points uniquely determines the status.) You would want to keep the status in the database if your are running A LOT of queries involving the status.

Comment: ^Yes, as Paul says, it's _denormalization_, which can be a valid strategy if you've carefully considered the overhead of the normalized situation (status is calculated on the fly) with the drawbacks of a denormalized state (possible data-conflicts, lag, etc.)

Comment: so at runtime I do a switch statement that checks the user points and sets the displayed status whenever status is requested?

Comment: Yes. *Especially* if the only place you use it is in displaying the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER changeUserStatus BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF NEW.userPoints > 100 THEN
         SET NEW.userStatus = 'lvl2';
     END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

`delimiter` allows the user of semicolons within in the trigger definition.

Of course, assumes that you hard code it. If you instead want to reference a table, I would use a different approach.

**EDIT:** If you want to reference your table `statuses` (which you provided in your edited question), then your approach depends on how many records you are updating.

If you are updating one at a time,

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER changeUserStatus BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     SET @status = (
         SELECT statusName
         FROM statuses
         WHERE NEW.userPoints BETWEEN s.minimumPoints AND s.maximumPoints
     );
     IF @status <> NEW.userStatus:
         SET NEW.userStatus = @status;
     END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

However, if you are updating many records at a time, it is likely more performant to run one query at the end. Unfortunately, MySQL only allows triggers that perform one operation per row.

So, I would create a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE refreshUserStatuses
     UPDATE users u
         JOIN statues s ON u.userPoints BETWEEN s.minimumPoints AND s.maximumPoints
     SET u.userStatus = s.statusName;
```

You will have to run `CALL refreshUserStatuses;` after updating users.

Comment: well I want to reference the table that I've provided in the updated question

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_status BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET @NEWSTATUS = (SELECT statusId 
                      FROM userStatuses 
                      WHERE NEW.userPoints BETWEEN minPoints AND maxPoints);
      IF @NEWSTATUS != OLD.userStatus THEN
        SET NEW.userStatus = @NEWSTATUS;    
      END IF;
  END;
```

This will get the status for the user's points and validate if he was already on that level or not. If not, the user will change status.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9dfc/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This code enables users to change their password:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  username   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  First_name VARCHAR(20),
  Last_name  VARCHAR(20),
  password   VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE change_password (
  id               INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  username         VARCHAR(20),
  old_password     VARCHAR(20),
  new_password     VARCHAR(20),
  comfirm_password VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

DELIMITER $$
create trigger nn before insert on change_password
for each row
begin
if new.comfirm_password!=new.new_password then
signal sqlstate '42000' set message_text="New password is not the same as comfirm password";
end if ;

if (new.old_password != (select password from users where username=new.username))then
signal sqlstate '42000' set message_text="Incorrect old password";
end if ;

if ((new.old_password = (select password from users where username=new.username)) && 
(new.new_password=new.comfirm_password)) then 
update users
set password =new.new_password where username=new.username;
end if;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```